# How to define a function to be undoable with a single `C-x u`?

Tags: elisp

Consider this toy example:

```
(defun foo ()
  (interactive)

  (replace-string "a" "A" nil (region-beginning) (region-end) nil)
  (replace-string "r" "R" nil (region-beginning) (region-end) nil)
)

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c F") 'foo)
```

The function `foo` replaces all a's and r's with A's and R's, respectively.  If one wants to undo it, however, a single undo (`C-x u`) isn't be enough; two are required.

I'm looking for a way to define `foo` such that only one `C-x u` is enough to undo everything it does.

Since the code above is only an example, I'm looking for solutions that do not depend on the specifics of `replace-string`.  IOW, the solution should work for any `foo` of the form

```
(defun foo ()
  (interactive)

  ;;
  ;; body
  ;;
)
```